# Reflecting *.class file

Tags: java, reflection

How to get java.lang.Class from *.class file?

I have a folder whicj contains *.class files. I need to reflect them all to java.lang.Class. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738393/how-to-use-urlclassloader-to-load-a-class-file#738422) answer and did so, as stated in the first option:

```
        URL[] classUrl = new URL[1];
        classUrl[0] = new URL("file:" + classFilesFolder);
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrl);
        Class c = ucl.loadClass("I DON'T KNOW CLASS NAMES HERE!");
```

The problem is that I don't know names of classes that I'm reflecting. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Usually a class called `Foo` gets compiled to a class file called `Foo.class`. Can you not tell from the file name?

Comment: Why can't you extract it from `classUrl`?

Comment: Right class name in my case is a packageName.class.Name, not just a className. ("models.myClass" instead of "myClass") - that's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `classFilesFolder` is `/home/user` and the files inside the folder have names like `/home/user/com/something/My.class`, the class name (including the package) will be `com.something.My`. So the class name is the full file name, with `classFilesFolder` removed, then change all forward slashes to dots and remove `.class` at the end.

Comment: no, i still can't load Class if I don't specify package name (**models**.myClass).

Comment: com.something.My in my example includes the package name. I rewrote the answer to be a little clearer.

Comment: I put my class files directly to folder classFilesFolder. These *.class files are intended to be imported. Probably better to abandon imoort *.class files and use the jar files?

Comment: Yes. The mapping of file path to package name is pretty standard,  whether inside a jar or outside one. Using a jar rather than separate files should help maintain the relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) to [parse a class file](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html), and then call [`getClassName()`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#getClassName%28%29) to find the name.