# Instantiate an object from source code compiled on-the-fly

Tags: java, reflection, javassist

I would like to know if there is a posibility to instance a class of an external file

For example:
Oreja oreja_object = getClassFromExternalFile("C:\oreja_file.java");

Thanks,
Cristina.

Comment: I wonder if there is any way this can be useful. You should just add the file as source.

Comment: Probably you could use JavaCompiler API

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki One use-case I could imagine is a plugin system where the end-users can add 3rd party plugins distributed as .java files to the application by putting them in some directory.

Comment: My idea is developing an app that accepts an external .java file (or a precompiled .class file) and instantiate that object in my program. My goal is to test a generic web service dynamically. Imagine a web service that expects a json-array of 5 entities, but those entities aren't inside the project. So I take a file, create N objects and send them to the Web Services and retrieve the output. Thats the main idea

Answer (score 3):

Cristina, you can load external `.class` files dynamically using a custom `ClassLoader`, such as `URLClassLoader`. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738393/how-to-use-urlclassloader-to-load-a-class-file).

You cannot load a `.java` source file directly. It must be compiled first, for example using the [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).