# Loading .class files via URLClassLoader - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reflection

I'm aware this question has been asked multiple times (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738393/how-to-use-urlclassloader-to-load-a-class-file)), but none of the answers appear to work for me.
This is a homework assignment, I'm supposed to "hack" several class files via the reflection API, but I can't even get them to load.

There are three `.class` files (Inscription.class, Decoder.class, Safe.class) I put in `D:\class\`. Then I try to load them via an URLClassLoader:

```
 public void Load() throws MalformedURLException {
        ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        File classFolder = new File("D://class//");
        // classFolder.exists() returns true at this point.

        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{classFolder.toURI().toURL()},loader);

        // urlClassLoader.classes is empty at this point, which is suspicous

         urlClassLoader.loadClass("Safe");
         // throws NoClassDefFoundError (wrong name: ea_6_1/Safe)
         // Interestingly, it seems to find a package name (ea_6_1)

         urlClassLoader.loadClass("ea_6_1.Safe");
         // throws ClassNotFoundException
    }
```

I also tried to load the files one by one, but apparently this shouldn't work, since URLClassLoader only accepts directories or JAR files:

```
   URL inscription = loader.getResource("Inscription.class");
   URL safe = loader.getResource("Safe.class");
   URL decoder = loader.getResource("Decoder.class");

   URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{inscription, safe, decoder});

   // Exact same behavior as above.
```

My classpath configuration looks like this:

[image]

Is this a configuration issue or am I using the URLClassLoader wrong? Is there maybe another way of loading class files?

Comment: It appears you have moved .class files around, without preserving the required directory structure.  A compiled Java class whose source was declared with `package ea_6_1;` *must* reside in a directory named `ea_6_1`.

Comment: @VGR Thanks, I found out the same a couple of minutes ago. Those files were as provided, there was no directory structure around them. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears someone has moved .class files around, without preserving the required directory structure.

A Java class declared with `package ea_6_1;` *must* reside in a directory named `ea_6_1` (in every Java implementation I know of, at least).