# Get class properties from class absolute path using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

im generating new classes using file package but when i want to get the class properties using reflection it doesn't work and it gave me the error bellow but when i refresh my package by clicking on the right button of my mouse and i click on refresh and i rerun my function it works.
So now i think that i need to change my method to get those properties by using absolut path instead of name of package.

**my code**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main7{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Class classe = Class.forName("com.test.model.Client");
        // affiche tous les attributs
        System.out.println("Attributs -------------------------------------");
        for (Field attribut : classe.getDeclaredFields()) {
           // System.out.print("   "+Modifier.toString(attribut.getModifiers()));
            String type = attribut.getType().getName();
            if(type.contains(".")) {
                String[] tab = type.split("\\.");
                type=tab[2];
            }
            System.out.println(type+" "+attribut.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

**error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ma.dxc.generator.model.Client
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at generatortest.Main7.main(Main7.java:16)
```

**good result**

```
Attributs -------------------------------------
long id
String name
String city
```

Comment: Have you included com.test.model.Client in your classpath somewhere?
The classloader needs to find the class

Comment: i tried to do that but i didn't succeed.

Comment: ok run me through it.. you have a file in:

proj/com/test/model/

called Client.java

Where are you running from? What is your classpath?

Comment: to be more clear im using openJPA to generate classes from database by running my code from another package, but the generated classes don't show up while my code is running.

Comment: I think you need to share a bit more info on how you set up openJPA so people can help you.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to get class properties using absolute path of the class ??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get class properties is like this:

```
Class klass = com.test.model.Client.class;
```

Or simply:

```
Class klass = Client.class;
```

If you've already imported the class above.

Or if you have an intance of an object:

```
Class klass = obj.getClass();
```

**Class.forName()** is used to dynamically load new classes into the system. And is not necessary to obtain the class properties through reflection.

Once you have the **Class** object you can obtain more info like **getDeclaredFields()** and others.

If you want to load something outside the current classpath you could use **URLClassLoader** like this:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { "file://path/to/jar/or/directory"});
Class klass = loader.loadClass("com.test.model.Client");
```

This article may be relevant as well: [How to use URLClassLoader to load a *.class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738393/how-to-use-urlclassloader-to-load-a-class-file)

**Class.forName()** won't look beyond your classpath. Its intended to dynamically load something that has already been added to your classpath.

Comment: I need to use reflection because at that time when I want to use the new class, it's just I file with java extension, and I need to use absolute path because classloader can't find it using package

Comment: I think if the classloader can't find it. I'm not sure Class.forName() is going to help.

You may want to try URLClassLoader to gain access to a class that is outside the known classpath.

Comment: FYI- "Reflection" is the act of using the Class object and its methods. Not Class.forName(). Though Class.forName() often implies reflection.

Comment: i think that i need a method that can help me to load class from string, can you help me with that?